# Semantic nuance between the phrasal verb "figure out" and the verb "grasp"

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning, verbs, word-difference

According to the dictionary definitions the phrasal verb **figure out** and the verb **grasp** can indicate very similar meanings and it strikes me that one can use them interchangeably. This is why I came to this question that how shall one distinguish them in a manner that he/she could use each one in a more appropriate case?!

Please have a look on the dictionary examples bellow:

> - Could you help me **figure out** this problem?
> - It takes most people some time to **figure out** new software.
> - The detective couldn't **figure out** the death reason!
> - He couldn't **figure out** anything about them.
> - I've read this book twice, but still I don't **grasp** it.
> - I couldn't **grasp** what he was trying to say.

As far as I am concerned, in all cases above, these two verbs can be replaced freely in the manner that both sentences convey an identical message to the reader! Am I right? If so, then is it a matter of personal preference when to use them or there is something that I am missing it?

Answer (score 5):

In most cases, I'd agree. Though take the first sentence, to "figure out" a problem. To me, this implies that you are wanting help to *solve* the problem.

If instead you said you were trying to "grasp" the problem, it sounds more like you are trying to *understand* the problem, let alone solve it.

Also, I wouldn't usually expect to hear someone request help to "grasp" something directly. This sounds natural:

> Can you help me figure out this problem?

This does not:

> Can you help me grasp this problem?

An alternative that does:

> I'm trying to grasp this problem. Can you help?

Comment: Yeah - I'd say *Can you help me grasp this problem?* might imply something along the lines of *Can you explain to me **why this is a problem** in the first place?* Whereas *Can you help me figure out this problem* implies that you know perfectly well it's a problem - you just want help *solving* it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Absolutely; well put!

Comment: In order to make it more clear and based on your statements, **I couldn't "figure out" what he was trying to say** should imply: (I couldn't understand why he was trying to say) while **I couldn't "grasp" what he was trying to say** means (I couldn't understand what he said). Right?

Comment: Or in my other example **I've read this book twice, but still I don't.......it** we cannot use "figure out" while the verb "grasp" works perfectly here in the manner that if we say: **I've read this book twice, but still I don't "figure it out"** means (I don't understand why or how it has been written, whereas if we say: **I've read this book twice, but still I don't grasp it** it means: "I cannot understand the book because of complexity. Right?

Comment: But in the sentence: **Can you ........ what he's trying to say** both of these verbs can be used freely and perfectly without any change in meaning! Right?

Answer (score 1):

"Grasp" and "figure out" do have very similar meanings, and can very often be used interchangeably:

> It takes a long time to "grasp"/"figure out" the complex social rules
>   in Island society.
>
> He never could seem to "grasp"/"figure out" trigonometry.

Both pairs mean the same thing.

But there is a slight difference between the two expressions, and in some situations it causes one of them to be more appropriate than the other. "Grasp" is usually used when you are talking about comprehending fully something that you are aware of, and "figure out" emphasizes the the active thought process of originating new concepts in your mind:

"I finally *figured out* the answer to the puzzle." Means that, based on the information you were given, you arrived at the answer, your original idea.

"I finally *grasped* the answer to the puzzle." sounds more like someone told you the answer, and after much thought, you were able to understand it.

"He often couldn't *grasp* how powerful he really was." means he couldn't fully understand the reality of his power.

You probably wouldn't say, "He often couldn't *figure out* how powerful he really was." because that sounds like he is completely ignorant of his great power. At any rate, ... those two sentences do have different implications.

So they're close and often interchangeable, but not identical.

More examples:

> "The detective *figured out* who the killer was."
>
> **Not** "The detective *grasped* who the killer was."
>
> "When our home burned down, it took us a full year to really *grasp*
>   it."
>
> **Not** "When our home burned down, it took us a full year to really *figure it out*."

Comment: Thank you Lorel; but could you please let me know of I am following you! Based on your and others' posts I guess in your first examples: **It takes a long time to "grasp"/"figure out" the complex social rules in Island society.** And **He never could seem to "grasp"/"figure out" trigonometry.**, the verb **grasp** works more appropriately although they are interchangeable; do you approve it?

Comment: Just because I listed "grasped" first in those first 2 sentences, I didn't mean to imply that "grasp" was better than "figure out" in those 2 cases. To my ears they are equally appropriate there, and in many, even most, other situations. *Sometimes*, though, it does make a difference that "grasp" emphasizes the passive comprehension of an existing concept, but "figure out" implies creative mental activity.

Answer (score 0):

Grasp, is a verb meaning to

seize and hold

synonyms include:  grip, clutch, clasp, hold, clench, lay hold of... etc

Therefore, logically, I describe it this way.

Grasp, is used  more to describe the physical act, that of the hand. Human or non human, with or without disposable thumb, for example: The Australopithecus afarensis grasped hold, squeezing ever so tightly,  the neck of the much smaller chimpanzee, choking it, no, not til death, but just long enough, for the dumb ape to figure out, that he was a lower animal, in the hierarchy of the great apes.

Next! We have a combination or two words...

Figure:

The word "Figure" means simply, to calculate or to work out somethings value. Whether it be in knowledge or number.

Out:

The word "out" in this context, is used to denote the fact that something here, and now is revealed or made public.

Thus we have the two words amalgamated  into the ingenious phrase:

Figure out...

This short phrase, should only be used, in terms where one is illuminated consciously, within their psyche or self, having  procured certain knowledge and understanding from a perceptual standpoint.

Thus, the two in question, "grasp" and "figure out" , are to be used, not as if equivalent. But as being perfect for two very different situations.